# Pocketbeagle Serial port communication issue with Honeywell HPMA115S0

Tags: c, linux, beagleboard

I would like to communicate with Honeywell HPMA115S0 sensor running a C program. Target system is a PocketBeagle running Debian.

I can communicate with the sensor using 'screen' utility by setting only port and BPS.
I can also communicate using python3 and Serial library, so i exclude any hardware problem.

But i cannot do it with C program. Everything seems to be good but when i expect an ACK i receive nothing. A curious aspect is if i run screen or the python script and close it, then i can use my C program that properly communicate.

I run stty to check the differences at system boot, then after C program and after the screen but nothing seems to be the cause. I think i have to set proper serial mask. Right now i use:

```
int fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
struct termios tty;
memset(&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

if(tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0) {
    printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}

tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; // Disable echo
tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHOE; // Disable erasure
tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHONL; // Disable new-line echo
cfsetospeed(&tty, 9600);
cfsetispeed(&tty, 9600);
if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
   printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}
```

Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure at all the following link will help, you may have already seen it, but the statement _"but I receive no data on the RX."_, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128814/beaglebone-black-serial-c) is so similar to your _"when i expect an ACK i receive nothing"_, that I thought you may see something there that may be useful.

Comment: You've posted how you configure the serial port, but not the code reading and writing from/to it. Please update your post with complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the Python script and the C program with strace and I noticed that the problem resides in:

```
cfsetospeed(&tty, 9600);
cfsetispeed(&tty, 9600);
```

It should use 'B9600' instead of '9600'.

The correct form is:

```
cfsetospeed(&tty, B9600);
cfsetispeed(&tty, B9600);
```

Answer (score 0):

What your terminal needs is the [non-canonical (a.k.a. raw) mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html). The GNU libc documentation has a nice [minimal example](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Noncanon-Example.html) of how it's set. Your code doesn't clear the `ICANON` flag which is probably the critical one. It should look something like this:

```
if(tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0) {
    printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}
tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO); /* Clear ICANON and ECHO. */
tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
cfsetospeed(&tty, 9600);
cfsetispeed(&tty, 9600);
if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &tty) != 0) {
   printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
}
```